# CdeIgniter Database Operation

Tags: php, codeigniter

I bought a script. And here is the original code:

```
public function delete_user($user_slug = null)
{
    empty($user_slug) and show_404();

    flash_message(
        'dashboard/login',
        is_login(),
        'unsuccess',
        'Please Login Then Try Again'
    );

    $user = $this->UsersModel->updateTable([
        'status' => '3',
    ], ['slug' => $user_slug]);
    flash_message(
        'list/users',
        $user,
        'unsuccess',
        "Something Went Wrong"
    );

    flash_message(
        'list/users',
        $user,
        'success',
        "User Deleted Successfully"
    );
}`
```

As you can see this function changes user status to "3" for delete user. But I don't want to change it. I want to add a number over an already existing value.

For example, every time the function runs, I want to change the previously "3" value to "3+1". If the value is already "4", I want to change it to "4+1". In short, instead of changing the value, I want to add a number to the existing value every time the function runs.

I tried:

```
$user = $this->UsersModel->updateTable([
    'status' => status+1,
```

but it doesn't work. Can you help me?

Comment: Just go back a step for a moment. Why would you want to increment a "status" field in this way? A status usually indicates a particular state that the record is in. If you just increment it without knowing what the previous status was, how can you be sure you'll get the correct status after the update? Maybe you are (mis-)using this  field for something else?

Comment: I will use it for something else by duplicating the function. So I won't touch this function.

Comment: You need to get the value of the status field via your UsersModel. Since we do not know your code, it is pretty difficult to help any further.

Comment: What version of Codeinter is this? Because the solution is a bit different from version 3 to version 4.

Comment: It’s Codeigniter 3.1.11, i can share UsersModel.php too